# How to find center of path in SVG Flutter

Tags: flutter, svg, center

I need to find the exact center point of the path in SVG. I used the path object is there any way to handle the right point to put text to the center of the path of SVG?
pathMetrics didn't get the center point. I use this path class =
class Path extends NativeFieldWrapperClass1

```
  transform = transform.replaceAll('matrix(', '').replaceAll(')', '');
  List<String> array = transform.split(',').toList();
  final double xScale = double.parse(array[0]) * 1.6;
  final double yScale = double.parse(array[3]) * 1.6;
  Matrix4 matrix4 = Matrix4.identity();
  matrix4.scale(xScale, yScale);

  double scaledSvgWidth = width * xScale;
  //double scaledSvgHeight = height * yScale;
  // calculate offset to center the svg image
  double offsetX = (size.width - scaledSvgWidth) / 3;
  Offset offset = Offset(offsetX, 0.0);

  final text = '30';
  final ParagraphBuilder paragraphBuilder = ParagraphBuilder(
    ParagraphStyle(
        fontSize: 10,
        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
        textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
        maxLines: null),
  )
    ..pushStyle(
      getTextStyle(),
    )
    ..addText(text);
  final Paragraph paragraph = paragraphBuilder.build()
    ..layout(ParagraphConstraints(width: size.width));

  final pathMetrics = paths[index].transform(matrix4.storage).shift(offset).computeMetrics();


  final pathMetricsList = pathMetrics.toList();
  final tangent = pathMetricsList[0].getTangentForOffset(3)!;
  final currLetterPos = tangent.position;
  canvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, currLetterPos);[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```